# ASP.NET 5 RC1 - Strong Name Validation Runtime Issue with using Kendo.Mvc nuget package

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

We are developing an application using ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 RC1. We have signed our project assembly with snk key file. We are using Kendo.Mvc nuget package version 2015.3.1120.0 which doesn't have strong name signed (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Kendo.Mvc/) including latest release of package. Now result of this we are facing runtime exception
"System.IO.FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'Kendo.Mvc, Version=2015.3.1120.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)".

As per previous knowledge we can bypass StrongName Validation via `<runtime>` tag in configuration section in application config file. How can I do that with ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 application?